What else do I need to do to have my custom WooCommerce Analytics filter applied to exports?
I'm working with WooCommerce Analytics, and have successfully added a dropdown to the orders and reports screens. The dropdown allows me to select whether or not to include subscription related orders in the data displayed on screen, and it works.
There is only limited information about extending WooCommerce Analytics found online, but all of them show only one place in JavaScript where a filter is used to add my dropdown to the page. I would think that by adding the dropdown to the page that WooCommerce would be smart enough to see the value it contains, and include the parameter in its request to do the export, but when I click on the "Download" button, the REST request does not contain my custom param "subtype" when on the Revenue screen. But even on the Orders screen where the "subtype" param is added to the request, the results are not any different than if the param wasn't there at all. Here is the payload for the Revenue export download:
{
    "report_args":{
        "orderby":"date",
        "order":"desc",
        "after":"2024-08-01T00:00:00",
        "before":"2024-08-26T23:59:59",
        "page":1,
        "per_page":25,
        "match":"all",
        "status_is":"completed",
        "extended_info":true
    },
    "email":true
}

You can see in that payload that WooCommerce added its own "status_is" parameter when I selected it. I want my "subtype" parameter to be added to the payload.
What else do I need to do to get the exports to match the on screen data? Here is the way I add the dropdown to the orders and revenue screens:
if(
    typeof wp !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof wp.hooks !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof wp.hooks.addFilter === 'function'
){
    // Orders screen
    wp.hooks.addFilter(
        'woocommerce_admin_orders_report_filters',
        'wass-wc-analytics-extension',
        ( originalFilters ) => {
            // Add the dropdown
            return [
                {
                    label: 'Subscription/Order Types',
                    staticParams: [],
                    param: 'subtype', // The query parameter that will be used
                    showFilters: () => true,
                    defaultValue: '1',
                    filters: [...(wcSettings.subtypes || [])]
                },
                ...originalFilters,
            ];
        }
    );

    // Revenue screen
    wp.hooks.addFilter(
        'woocommerce_admin_revenue_report_filters',
        'wass-wc-analytics-extension',
        ( originalFilters ) => {
            // Add the dropdown
            return [
                {
                    label: 'Subscription/Order Types',
                    staticParams: [],
                    param: 'subtype', // The query parameter that will be used
                    showFilters: () => true,
                    defaultValue: '1',
                    filters: [...(wcSettings.subtypes || [])]
                },
                ...originalFilters,
            ];
        }
    );
}

I can show more code if necessary, but I believe these are the relevant snippets needed.
